# Aligning button and textview components vertically android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am trying to make my `Button` component and my `TextView` component aligned vertically and also centered. Also a bit of spacing between each other. Right now they are simply on top of each other.

[image]

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dueDateSection"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editSection"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_edit_item_layout_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_edit_item_layout_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
            android:text="Select Date"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnDatePicker"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btnDatePicker" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use linear layout ...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B1"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YOUR TEXT"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

this may helps you.

Answer (score 2):

use this ....

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dueDateSection"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
        android:marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Select Date"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnDatePicker"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="Hi this is simple"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dueDateSection"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editSection"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
            android:text="Select Date" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnDatePicker"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="CORE JAVA"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: this will look like this]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on to the above answers ,you must prefer using a Linear layout whenever you want all your components  to be aligned vertically(or horizontally).

Since in Relative layout,the components are Positioned with respect to other components,it increases the complexity of the layout.And when you generate the Layout using Design it isn't effective.

Few tips on Linear Layout if you are using it in the future :

1. Use `android:orientation="vertical"` for components to be aligned vertically .
   `android:orientation="horizontal"` for components to be aligned horizontally.
2. Use weightSum and weight as shown below :

   ```
   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:text="New Button"
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1" />

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:id="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="2" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:text="New Button"
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1" />

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="2" />
   ```

Here the Layout is Assigned a total weight of 12 and the children are assigned with different weights, (Ratio of heights of Button to EditText is 1 is to 2 and all 4 children together occupy half the Total Height of the Layout is the Sum of weights of all Children put together is 6 and weightSum is 12)

[image: Linear Layout]